# ipad: predictive search in a popover

Tags: xcode, ipad, ios4

I want to implement this

1) when user start typing in a textfield a popOver flashes and shows the list of items in a table view in the popover as per the string entered in textfield.

2) Moreover this data should be refreshed with every new letter entered.

kind of predictive search.

Please help me with this and suggest possible ways to implement this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you have a pretty good idea of an implementation already. My suggestion would be to present a UITableView in a popover with the search bar at the top, then simply drive the table view's data source using the search term and call `reloadData` on the table view every time the user types into the box.

Answer (score 7):

[UISearchDisplayController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UISearchDisplayController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) does most of the heavy lifting for you.

Place a [UISearchBar](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UISearchBar_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/UISearchBar) (not a UITextField) in your view, and wire up a UISearchDisplayController to it.

```
// ProductViewController.h
@property IBOutlet UISearchBar *searchBar;
@property ProductSearchController *searchController;

// ProductViewController.m
- (void) viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    searchBar.placeholder = @"Search products";
    searchBar.showsCancelButton = YES;

    self.searchController = [[[ProductSearchController alloc]
                                    initWithSearchBar:searchBar
                                    contentsController:self] autorelease];
}
```

I usually subclass UISearchDisplayController and have it be it's own delegate, searchResultsDataSource and searchResultsDelegate. The latter two manage the result table in the normal manner.

```
// ProductSearchController.h
@interface ProductSearchController : UISearchDisplayController
            <UISearchDisplayDelegate, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>

// ProductSearchController.m
- (id)initWithSearchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
                contentsController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
    self = [super initWithSearchBar:searchBar contentsController:viewController];

    self.contents = [[NSMutableArray new] autorelease];
    self.delegate = self;
    self.searchResultsDataSource = self;
    self.searchResultsDelegate = self;

    return self;
}
```

Each keypress in the searchbar calls `searchDisplayController:shouldReloadTableForSearchString:`. A quick search can be implemented directly here.

```
- (BOOL) searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController*)controller
            shouldReloadTableForSearchString:(NSString*)searchString
{
    // perform search and update self.contents (on main thread)
    return YES;
}
```

If your search might take some time, do it in the background with [NSOperationQueue](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Reference/NSOperationQueue_class/Reference/Reference.html). In my example, ProductSearchOperation will call `showSearchResult:` when and if it completes.

```
// ProductSearchController.h
@property INSOperationQueue *searchQueue;

// ProductSearchController.m
- (BOOL) searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController*)controller
        shouldReloadTableForSearchString:(NSString*)searchString
{
    if (!searchQueue) {
        self.searchQueue = [[NSOperationQueue new] autorelease];
        searchQueue.maxConcurrentOperationCount = 1;
    }

    [searchQueue cancelAllOperations];
    NSInvocationOperation *op = [[[ProductSearchOperation alloc]
            initWithController:self
            searchTerm:searchString] autorelease];
    [searchQueue addOperation:op];

    return NO;
}

- (void) showSearchResult:(NSMutableArray*)result
{
    self.contents = result;
    [self.searchResultsTableView
            performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(reloadData)
            withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
}
```

Comment: In interface builder, a UISearchBar seems styled to appear (as named) in a toolbar, whereas as UITextField is styled to look good on a blank page. Is there a way to make a UISearchBar that does not need to be in a "bar" - such as if you wanted to have multiple search-enabled textfields on a page?

Comment: @radven You should ask that as a top level question on the site.

Comment: Done - posted here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10792578/making-a-uisearchbar-a-drop-in-replacement-for-a-uitextfield

Comment: I am trying to build upon your example, and having trouble getting UISearchDisplayController to trigger the results popover when it is not in a toolbar. Is this possible?

Comment: can i have a sample program on this