# Making a UISearchBar a drop-in replacement for a UITextField?

Tags: ios5, uitextfield, uisearchbar

In interface builder, a UISearchBar seems styled to appear (as you would expect, considering how it is named) in a toolbar, whereas as UITextField is styled to look good on a blank page.

Is there a way to make a UISearchBar that does not need to be in a "bar" - such as if you wanted to have multiple search-enabled textfields on a page?

My ultimate goal is to have a page full of UITextFields - each of which pops up a predictive search popover as the user fills out the form. I can do the predictive search in a navigation bar - but I want to enable every field on the page.

Help and pointers to sample code is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Actually, in iOS 5, UISearchBar is so incredibly customizable in appearance that you can make it look just about however you want it to look. So there isn't (and never was, really) any need for it to be in a "bar".

This [horrible-looking thing](https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/master/figures/pios_2506.png?raw=true) is a search bar, created simply to demonstrate how truly customizable a UISearchBar is!

Comment: Laying out my UI in Xcode - the UISearchBar offers "Default", "Black Opaque", and "Black Translucent" styles - all of which have the "bar" frame around them and none of which work as a standing for a UITextField on a blank white page.  Setting the tint to solid white hides the bar look, but still leaves behind an underline. I can't figure out how to make it unadorned.

Comment: Read the docs on UISearchBar. Use code, not the nib editor, to get the look you want.

Comment: I've read the docs and searched Stack Overflow - I haven't yet seen a clearly described way to make an unadorned UISearchBar. Very likely there is something obvious I am missing.

Comment: Can you post some sample code so we can see how you did this?

Comment: @dacopenhagen How who did what?

Comment: @matt - I've looked at customizing the uisearchbar as much as you have and haven't found apple's docs that clear.  any chance you could post the code it took to fully customize it like that?  ex: the custom x, etc.

Comment: @dacopenhagen It's all right there in the docs (UISeachBar class) under "Customizing Appearance". For example, for the custom x, look at `imageForSearchBarIcon:state:`.